# Prove that a definition in set theory is sound

Tags: order-theory

I have a problem to show that the following definition is sound.

Definition: Let $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ be order types. We say $\Theta_1 \prec \Theta_2$ If there are order sets 
$\langle A_1,\prec_1\rangle $ and $\langle A_2,\prec_2\rangle$ of order type $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ respectively such that $A_1$ is similar to a subset of $A_2$.

Prove that the definition is sound.

What is "sound" in this context means?
And How can I prove it?

Thank you

Comment: You have to show that it doesn't depend on the choice of $A_1$ and $\prec_1$.

Comment: Some people would say [well-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined).